# jQuery operator is(':visible') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and I was going through the modal.js code and found the below code:

```
$target.one('show.bs.modal', function (showEvent) {
  if (showEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return // only register focus restorer if modal will actually get shown
  $target.one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $this.is(':visible') && $this.trigger('focus')
  })
})
```

I tried to understand the above code, so I [made a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v36zoy1g/).

Now if you see the if conditional in the code:

```
 if ($this.is(':visible')) {
        $('input').trigger('focus');
        console.log($this + ' ' + 'is visible');

    } else {
        console.log($this + ' ' + 'invisible');
    }
```

Now even if I have the following display rule i.e.

```
input {
  display:none;
}
```

The if condition still passes; that's my first difficulty. Why does the if condition pass?

My second difficulty is the line inside the if condition i.e.

```
$this.trigger('focus');
```

Now even though the if condition passes the input doesn't get the focus. Why?

Comment: should that $this be $(this)? You are not saving it anywhere.

Comment: @peterpeterson , check the fiddle , that snippet is referencing the fiddle

Comment: @peterpeterson he does in the fiddle.
But here, when I set `display: none;`, the if condition doesn't pass, and the console.log reads "invisible".

Comment: shouldn't it be: $target.on('show.bs.modal', function (showEvent) ... instead of $target.one('show.bs.modal', function (showEvent) {?

Comment: @peterpeterson `on` creates a continuous event, while `one` creates an event that only triggers once, and then destroys itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some minor chances to your code, and now it all seems to work for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$target = $('input');
$target.trigger('focus');

$target.one('show.bs.modal', function (showEvent) {
    $this = $(this);

    console.log($this);

    if ($this.is(':visible')) {
        $this.focus();
    } else {
        console.log($this + ' ' + 'invisible');
    }

    $target.one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $this.is(':visible') && $this.trigger('focus')
    });
});

$target.trigger('show.bs.modal');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v36zoy1g/2/

To focus an element, you don't need fancy code. the `.focus()` function does the job for you!
And actually, I think that's about it, can't remember anything else I changed to be honest. :p

Comment: if u cn comment the lines you changed , i'll accept ur answer :D

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik added 2 lines of text. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't cached `$(this)` on `$this`.

You can use:

```
$this = $(this) before you use $this in your code.
```

Comment: @dude see the fiddle pls .